# Create mutliple instances for every loop

Tags: c#, loops, instance, skype, skype4com

I want to be able to create a new 'group chat' every time the loop occurs but it will only create it once because I don't know how to create another instance of the chat.

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < Convert.ToInt32(StartingV2); ii++)
{
    var chat = skype.CreateChatMultiple(collection);//Want to create a new one these every loop
    chat.OpenWindow();
    chat.Topic = StartingV1;
    foreach (User i in collection)
    {
        chat.SendMessage("Hello and goodbye, " + i.Handle);
    }
    chat.Leave();
    Thread.Sleep(300);
}
```

I cannot figure out how to make a new 'var chat', with testing or searching myself.

Comment: Without seeing `skype.CreateChatMultiple`, how can we know what is returned?

Comment: @AdamKDean The OP didn't write it himself/herself, it's from the skype API.

Comment: I'm not sure what it does as ant said its the API.

Comment: Maybe, since the collection of users is the same at each loop, skype does not create a new chat but it returns you the existing one...
(does it make sense to have more than one chat with the same people ?)

Comment: @Antonijn it would be nice for OP to include a link to said API, or to at least provide the summary for the method, or tag the post as skype API. It could be from anything I am sure you'd agree.